# Check column IS NULL not working in Case Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case, sql-view

[image]

I am trying to check a column which belongs to View "IS NULL" and it works good with select statement:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Invoice_Number]
  ,[Invoice_Date]
  ,[Invoice_Amount]
  ,[Invoice_CoCd]
  ,[Invoice_vendor]
  ,[Invoice_PBK]
  ,[Invoice_DType]
  ,[Invoice_DueDate]
  ,[Invoice_ClgDate] FROM [dbo].[viewABC] where   Invoice_PBK IS NULL
```

Now I have an update statement, where I need to update a column in a table based on NULL in VIEW:

```
UPDATE cis
    SET
    cis.InvoiceStatus = 
    (
    CASE 

    WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.[Invoice_PBK])) IS NULL THEN 
    'HELLO'  
    WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.Invoice_DType)) = 'RD' 
    THEN        '233'  END)
FROM 
    [dbo.[tblABC] cis,
    [dbo].[viewABC] imd 
WHERE [condition logic]
```

These is no issue with where condition, the `IS NULL` in the `CASE` expression causing the problem.

Can someone help please?

Comment: You appear to be missing an `END` to your `CASE` **expression**. There is no `Case` Statement in T-SQL.

Comment: Is it not updating?  Did you try to run your update statement as a select statement first?

Comment: @Larnu: I have corrected it

Comment: What error you have?

Comment: @TinyHaitian : I am calling this update statement (in stored procedure) from c# console application

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: CIS.InvoiceStatus gets updated with NULL

Comment: Then `Invoice_PBK` does not have a value of `NULL`, and `Invoice_DType` dosen't have a value of ``RD'`; as a result, `NULL` is returned. If a `CASE` **expression** never evaluates to True, then `NULL` is returned,

Comment: Then add an `ELSE` condition   `ELSE 'No Match' END` By default if case doesnt match any condition consider `ELSE  NULL` by default

Comment: @Larnu: CIS.InvoiceStatus gets updated with NULL, rather it should get updated with value "HELLO"

Comment: @Larnu : Invoice_PBK has NULL , my select statement returns one row. But update statement not working

Comment: Then your logic is wrong, @Avinesh. It'll only be updated to `'HELLO'` **if** `imd.[Invoice_PBK]` has a value of `NULL`; if it doesn't, it won't be. (also, trimming a `NULL` is completely pointless, and they should be removed).

Comment: *"Invoice_PBK has NULL "* it clearly does not, I'm afraid. As, otherwise, `cis.InvoiceStatus` would not have a value of `NULL`. It's time for sample data and expected results here, please.

Comment: @Larnu I have posted  a pic which explains Invoice_pbk IS NULL

Comment: That picture gives us but one piece of the puzzle, @Avinesh . We need sample data that we can use the **replicate** the problem. With what we have, the statements I have made can only be true.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this expression:

```
cis.InvoiceStatus =
CASE 
    WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.[Invoice_PBK])) IS NULL THEN 
        'HELLO'  
    WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.Invoice_DType)) = 'RD' THEN
        '233'  
END
```

And this symptom:

> CIS.InvoiceStatus gets updated with NULL

The obvious conclusion is **neither** `WHEN` condition is met, and therefore the result of the `CASE` expression is `NULL`.

Maybe you wanted this, which will preserve the original value in that situation:

```
cis.InvoiceStatus =
CASE 
    WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.[Invoice_PBK])) IS NULL THEN 
        'HELLO'  
    WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.Invoice_DType)) = 'RD' THEN
        '233'  
    ELSE
        cis.InvoiceStatus
END
```

Or maybe you wanted this, to also match an empty string value:

```
cis.InvoiceStatus =
CASE 
    WHEN NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.[Invoice_PBK])),'') IS NULL THEN 
        'HELLO'  
    WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.Invoice_DType)) = 'RD' THEN
        '233'  
END
```

It's also worth pointing out the two `WHEN` conditions are looking at two different columns.

Finally, it may be worth a data clean-up project here. Needing to do an `LTRIM()` will break any chance of using indexes on those fields (`RTRIM()` is slightly less bad), and index use cuts to the core of database performance.

Comment: CIS.InvoiceStatus gets updated with NULL, rather it should get updated with "HELLO"

Comment: Fyi, if i try to match with Invoice_DType, i dont have any issues. The issue occurs when i try to do with Invoice_PBK IS NULL

Comment: My original value will be ' ' and currently i try to update with 'HELLO'. It is not working and getting updated as NULL

Comment: Empty strings and NULL are **not** the same thing. If you do an `IS NULL` check, it will result as `false` for an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just test your Logic piece by piece.
Try

```
SELECT ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(imd.[Invoice_PBK])),'Hey Im Null')
FROM 
    [dbo].[tblABC] cis,
    [dbo].[viewABC] imd 
WHERE [condition logic]
```

See if you get that String value on your returned column(s) from the Query. Then, build from there. It could be something as simple as the **JOIN**. Which I'm not a fan of that old syntax but, without more info on this table other than `[conditions]`. It's hard to just guess an answer for you. You have no detailed evidence that helps us. It very well could be your conditions but, you're saying "condition logic" and that does nothing for the group on this thread.